# podman: rootless container: permissions for container user

Tags: deployment, podman

In `nginx` podman container `nginx` user is used to run `nginx` server.

On the host machine `ls -alh`:

```sh
drwxrwx--- 2 myuser myuser 4.0K Aug 10 22:23 .
drwxrwx--- 3 myuser myuser 4.0K Aug 10 22:59 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 myuser myuser   46 Aug 10 22:24 .htpasswd
```

The same folder inside container `ls -alh`:

```sh
drwxrwx--- 2 root root 4.0K Aug 10 22:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Aug 10 11:05 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 root root   46 Aug 10 22:24 .htpasswd
```

`nginx` user inside container can't access `.htpasswd` because of `o-rwx`.

Question: what is the commonly used pattern to handle this kind of cases in **rootless** container universally? Maybe it is possible to create group (used later as file-group owner) which gathers all ranges from `subuid`/`subgid` for particular host user - but how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

By using the command-line option `--uidmap` you can  specify how the *myuser* UID and the *myuser* sub UIDs are mapped into the container.
(See the [man page](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/source/markdown/podman-run.1.md#--uidmapcontainer_uidfrom_uidamount) for `podman run`).

The command-line option `--gidmap` works in the same way but for GIDs instead of UIDs.

Let's look up the UID and GID for the user *nginx* in the container image **docker.io/library/nginx**

```
$ podman run --rm docker.io/library/nginx grep nginx /etc/passwd
nginx:x:101:101:nginx user,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
$
```

Result:

- **UID**: 101
- **GID**: 101

The numbers are later used when setting two shell variables

```
$ container_uid=101
$ container_gid=101
```

(The shell variables *container_uid* and *container_gid* don't have any meaning outside this post.
They are just introduced to make the answer easier to read)

##### Take a look in the files /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid on the host

The user *myuser* has these sub UIDs and sub GIDs.

```
$ grep myuser /etc/subuid
myuser:231072:65536
$ grep myuser /etc/subgid
myuser:231072:65536
$
```

Result:

*myuser* has 65536 sub UIDs and  65536 sub GIDs.

The numbers are later used when setting two shell variables

```
$ subuid_size=65536
$ subgid_size=65536
```

(The shell variables *subuid_size* and *subgid_size* don't have any meaning outside this post.
They are just introduced to make the answer easier to read)

Instead of looking up *subuid_size* and *subgid_size*  in */etc/subuid* and */etc/subgid*, a more general method is to run the commands

```
 subuid_size=$(( $(podman info --format "{{ range .Host.IDMappings.UIDMap }}+{{.Size }}{{end }}" ) - 1 ))
 subgid_size=$(( $(podman info --format "{{ range .Host.IDMappings.GIDMap }}+{{.Size }}{{end }}" ) - 1 ))
```

The advantage is that this also works when the file */etc/nsswitch.conf* is used instead of */etc/subuid* and */etc/subgid*. (See [`man subuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/subuid.5.html))

##### *Demo 1*: map the user *myuser* on the host to the user *root* inside the container

There is no need to specify `--uidmap`  nor `--gidmap` because this is the standard mapping.

Create the world writable directory *demo1*

```
$ mkdir demo1
$ chmod 777 demo1
$
```

Create a new file, running as *root* inside the container:

```
$ podman run --rm \
    -v ./demo1:/dir:Z \
      docker.io/library/nginx touch /dir/created_by_root
$
```

Create a new file, running as *nginx* inside the container:

```
$ podman run --rm \
    --user 101:101 \
    -v ./demo1:/dir:Z \
      docker.io/library/nginx touch /dir/created_by_nginx
$
```

List the files on the host

```
$ ls -l demo1
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1  231172  231172 0 Aug 27 20:24 created_by_nginx
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser myuser 0 Aug 27 20:22 created_by_root
$
```

Result: The file *created_by_root* is owned by *myuser*:*myuser*

##### *Demo 2*: map the user *myuser* on the host to the user *nginx* inside the container

Create the world writable directory *demo2*

```
$ mkdir demo2
$ chmod 777 demo2
$
```

Create a new file, running as *root* inside the container:

```
$ subuid_size=65536
$ subgid_size=65536
$ container_uid=101
$ container_gid=101
$ podman run --rm \
    --uidmap=0:1:$container_uid \
    --uidmap=$((container_uid + 1)):$((container_uid + 1)):$((subuid_size - $container_uid)) \
    --uidmap=$container_uid:0:1 \
    --gidmap=0:1:$container_gid \
    --gidmap=$((container_gid + 1)):$((container_gid + 1)):$((subgid_size - $container_gid)) \
    --gidmap=$container_gid:0:1 \
    -v ./demo2:/dir:Z \
      docker.io/library/nginx touch /dir/created_by_root
$
```

Create a new file, running as *nginx* inside the container.

```
$ subuid_size=65536
$ subgid_size=65536
$ container_uid=101
$ container_gid=101
$ podman run --rm \
    --user $container_uid:$container_gid \
    --uidmap=0:1:$container_uid \
    --uidmap=$((container_uid + 1)):$((container_uid + 1)):$((subuid_size - $container_uid)) \
    --uidmap=$container_uid:0:1 \
    --gidmap=0:1:$container_gid \
    --gidmap=$((container_gid + 1)):$((container_gid + 1)):$((subgid_size - $container_gid)) \
    --gidmap=$container_gid:0:1 \
    -v ./demo2:/dir:Z \
      docker.io/library/nginx touch /dir/created_by_nginx
$
```

List the files on the host

```
$ ls -l demo2
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser myuser 0 Aug 27 20:26 created_by_nginx
-rw-r--r--. 1  231072  231072 0 Aug 27 20:25 created_by_root
$
```

Result: The file *created_by_nginx* is owned by *myuser*:*myuser*

##### Conclusion

Use `--uidmap` and `--gidmap` in the same way as in **Demo 2**.

##### Troubleshooting tip

I wrote a troubleshooting tip:
[*Passed-in devices or files can't be accessed in rootless container (UID/GID mapping problem)*](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#34-passed-in-devices-or-files-cant-be-accessed-in-rootless-container-uidgid-mapping-problem) that contains the method described in **Demo 2**

Comment: This should be the best answer. It resolves so many of my problems trying to have a single non-root host user to run multiple containers that run with different internal uid/gids and all have to access and write to host mounted volumes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out what is the initial host UID for the container's *nginx* UID (just touch a file from the container using the user under which `nginx` is running, or check its log files, or check the running *nginx* process. Then use `stat` or `ls -ln` from the initial host user): some big UID value, let's suppose it's 100030.

Then from the initial host's unprivileged user you can use [`setfactl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfacl.1.html) to grant additional access to user 100030. This should be something like:

```
setfacl -R -m u:100030:rX,d:u:100030:rX folder
```

If you want the *nginx* user to be able to write (which might not be a good idea), you can replace `rX` with `rwX` or do it only in select directories. The duplication starting with `d:` stands for *default* ACLs, so newly created directories and files also inherit the same additional ACLs. When ACLs are set, output of `ls` displays a `+` and the ACL mask instead of the group, so it might look surprising.

Here are various references about ACLs:

- [Debian LXC's README](https://salsa.debian.org/lxc-team/lxc/-/blob/debian/1%254.0.6-2/debian/README.Debian#L75) (which gave me the idea),
- [POSIX Access Control Lists on Linux](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html)
- [`acl(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html)